# Caching ignite client node

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I'm writing a back-end application which is supposed to receive request from clients and perform some operations with ignite cache. The issue is I need low-latency response time and recreating `Ignite` client node to perform some operation with cache is totally unacceptable.

Is it common to create `Ignite` client node once on application startup and then use it any time the back-end received request from client that requires some operations with Ignite cache. I mean something like that:

```
public class Handler{

    private static final Ignite igniteClient;
    static{
        Ignition.setClientMode(true);
        igniteClient = Ignition.start();
    } 
    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5);

    private void handle(){
        semaphore.acquire();
        //use igniteClient
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's common to create Ignite client nodes on application startup and then reuse it.

Moreover, it's a not a good idea to create new client for each request, because it will lead to topology changes on each NODE_JOIN & NODE_LEFT events, which lead to creating new objects and connections for each client on a server nodes.